# Using stripe in Flutter Web! How to transfer customer_email?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I want to create a subscription page in flutter, with stripe. It works fine, beside I cannot transfer the customer_email to stripe.

That is my code, I added the parameter from the stripe api, as you can see below. But the program crashes...

The Stripe Api has this option.

```
@JS()
library stripe;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe_demo/constants.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart';

void redirectToCheckout(BuildContext _) async {
  final stripe = Stripe(apiKey);
  stripe.redirectToCheckout(CheckoutOptions(
    lineItems: [
      LineItem(price: nikesPriceId, quantity: 1),
    ],
  **  customer_email: "test@gmail.com",**
    mode: 'subscription',
    successUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/#/success',
    cancelUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/#/cancel',
  ));
}

@JS()
class Stripe {
  external Stripe(String key);

  external redirectToCheckout(CheckoutOptions options);
}

@JS()
@anonymous
class CheckoutOptions {
  external List<LineItem> get lineItems;

  external String get mode;

  external String get successUrl;

  external String get cancelUrl;

  **external String get customer_email;**

  external factory CheckoutOptions({
    List<LineItem> lineItems,
    String mode,
    String successUrl,
    String cancelUrl,
    String sessionId,
   ** String customer_email,**
  });
}

@JS()
@anonymous
class LineItem {
  external String get price;

  external int get quantity;

  external factory LineItem({String price, int quantity});
}
```

Here is the error:

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:51110/k2ADZWot2J4=
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9104?uri=http://127.0.0.1:51110/k2ADZWot2J4=
You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However, live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.
IntegrationError: Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: customer_email is not an accepted parameter.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `redirectToCheckout` like this is deprecated and no longer something Stripe recommends, but for that pattern the parameter would be `customerEmail`:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-customerEmail

Instead of creating the session like this, you should use your own back end to call the session create endpoint ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create)), and then redirect the customer to the session `url` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url)), using either a server or client redirect.